# R List data Type in Fortran

Tags: r, fortran, fortran2003

I need help representing R data type in Fortran.

My R code:

`mList <- list()`

I want to use `mList` in a Fortran function by passing it as an argument to the Fortran function. What is the corresponding R `list()` data type in Fortran?

My Fortran code

```
function fun(mList)
<XXX> mList
...
end function
```

What should I have in place of `XXX`?

Comment: From what I read on [Lists in R](http://www.r-tutor.com/r-introduction/list), it's a simple 1D vector. Supposing that all the data is of the same type (i.e., all integers), then you might be able to use `integer, dimension(:) mList`, but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: Thanks Kyle, I actually came to think the same much later. But my catch is the data type of the data in the list. R is pretty dynamic and so the list may be holding different data types. I am not sure how Fortran will take to this at runtime. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: If the list contains different types, then Fortran more than likely will not accept it.